# How to add a variable in the json string in a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, json

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_procedure1`(
    out try varchar(50)
)
BEGIN
    select @var1 :=count(*) from book.books;
    select @var2 :=count(*) from book.authors;
    set try =  ({"Count1": @var1, {"Count2 : @var2});
END
```

expected output {"Count1": 79, {"Count2 : 50} as there are 79 & 50 entries respectively

Comment: {"Count1": 79, {"Count2 : 50}
// as there are 79 entires in the book table and 50 entries in the authors table.                       i want to print the @var1 variable in the json format but i am not sure about the approach. Also i want to print multiple variables similar to these.Please help me asap.
thank you

Comment: The format you show is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 2):

You can to achieve this using next stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE a INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE b INT DEFAULT 0;
    
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO b FROM `books`;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO a FROM `authors`;

    SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
      'books', b,
      'authors', a
    ) AS 'Result';
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [the JSON_OBJECT() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object) to format JSON values:

```
SET try = JSON_OBJECT('Count1', @var1, 'Count2', @var2);
```

If you aren't using a version of MySQL that supports this function, it's time to upgrade. Older versions of MySQL are now past their end-of-life.

Comment: Yes i am using the latest version of MySQL. I get this error when i try to take count of 6 tables Error Code: 1406 Data too long for column 'try' at row 1

Comment: That error seems pretty clear. What do you need help on?

Comment: Yes i got it Thank You for Your Help

Answer (score 1):

```sql
CREATE 
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
PROCEDURE `new_procedure1` ( out try varchar(50) )
SELECT JSON_OBJECT( 'books', 
                    (select count(*) from book.books),
                    'authors', 
                    (select count(*) from book.authors) )
INTO try;
```

Comment: Thank you but i wanted to store the count in the variable.

Comment: @AnishaChavan *i wanted to store the count in the variable.* ??? The result is placed into the output variable. `CALL new_procedure1(@output); SELECT @output;`. If you want the result to be placed into the output stream then simply remove `INTO try` (and remove parameter variable too).